# HTML5 application cache, duplicated storage?

Tags: html, caching

If I specify an application cache manifest that says, "cache foo.js" and use the same manifest on `http://example.com/foo.html` and `http://example.com/bar.html` will then `foo.js` be cached twiced or is it smart enough to recognize it as the same resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will recognize already cached files. So in your example, it will be cached only once.